# Angular2 - adding [_ngcontent-mav-x] to styles

Tags: css, typescript, angular

I'm setting up a basic angular app, and I'm trying to inject some css to my views. This is an example of one of my components:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig } from 'angular2/router';

import { LandingComponent } from './landing.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './portfolio.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'portfolio-app',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/template.html',
    styleUrls: ['../app/styles/template.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/landing', name: 'Landing', component: LandingComponent, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/portfolio', name: 'Portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent }
])

export class AppComponent { }
```

Now the .css file is requested from my server, and when I inspect the page source, I can see it was added to the head. But something weird is happening:

```
<style>@media (min-width: 768px) {


    .outer[_ngcontent-mav-3] {
        display: table;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .mainContainer[_ngcontent-mav-3] {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .appContainer[_ngcontent-mav-3] {
        width: 95%;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .heightElement[_ngcontent-mav-3] {
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
}</style>
```

gets generated from this file:

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* center the mainContainer */

    .outer {
        display: table;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .mainContainer {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .appContainer {
        width: 95%;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .heightElement {
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
}
```

Can somebody please explain where the _ngcontent-mav tag comes from, what does it stand for and how to get rid of it?

I think this is the reason why my style is not getting applied to my templates.

If you need more info about the app structure, please checkout my [gitRepo](https://github.com/Shooshte/PortfolioV3), or ask and I'll add the code to the question.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The default encapsulation is [ViewEncapsulation#Emulated](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewEncapsulation-enum.html), check it out.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**update2**

`::slotted` is now supported by all new browsers and can be used with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

**update**

`/deep/` and `>>>` are deprecated.
**`::ng-deep`** replaces them. `::-deep` is also marked deprecated in source and the docs, but this means that it will also be removed eventually.

I think it depends on what W3C comes up with for theming the shadow DOM (like https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-shadow-parts/)

It's basically a workaround until all browsers support that natively and `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` can be removed entirely.

`::ng-deep` is also supported in SASS (or will be, depending on the SASS implementation)

**original**

View encapsulation helps to prevent styles bleeding into or out of components. The default encapsulation is `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` where classes like `_ngcontent-mav-x` are added to component tags and also styles are rewritten to only apply to matching classes.

This emulates to some degree the default behavior of the shadow DOM.

You can disable this encapsulation adding `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to the `@Component()` decorator.

Another way is the recently (re-)introduced shadow piercing CSS combinators `>>>`, `/deep/`, and `::shadow`. These combinators were introduced for styling shadow DOM but are deprecated there. Angular introduce them recently until other mechanisms like CSS variables are implemented.
See also https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7563 (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta10-2016-03-17)

`>>>` and `/deep/` are equivalent and using this combinators makes the styles ignore the the added helper classes (`_ngcontent-mav-x`)

```
* >>> my-component, /* same as */
* /deep/ my-component {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

applies to all `my-component` tags not matter how deep they are nested in other components.

```
some-component::shadow * {
  background-color: green;
}
```

applies to all elements in the template of `some-component`, but not further descendants.

They can also be combined

```
* /deep/ my-component::shadow div {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

this applies to all div elements in the template of all `my-component` templates no matter how deep `my-component` is nested in other components.

`/deep/`, `>>>`, and `::shadow` can only be used with

- `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`
- `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`
- `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native` when the browser supports them natively (Chrome does but prints a warning in the console that they are deprecated) or
  when the browser doesn't native support shadow DOM and the
  web_components polyfills are loaded.

For a simple example see also the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hc56mk07v0GD4W8rVzz1?p=preview) from this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/36226061/217408

See also this presentation from ng-conf 2016 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5Bvy4KhIs0

Comment: If I use /deep/in css of  a component, the css affects all page or only the component? (I'm using D3 so I needed to use /deep/, the others didn't work)

Comment: `/deep/` affects the component where you add the CSS and all its children.

Comment: Ok, so If I use a component for make a graph with D3 and use `/deep/` and the "parent component" call this component, it no affects to other parent component. Great!

Comment: No, parents or siblings won't be affected. If it does use `:host /deep/ xxx { }`. This changed so often since I started using Angular2 that I'm not sure what the most recent status is.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you for this, Im upgrading my code from AngularJS to Angular 2/5 and it has been a nightmare. I have a question, why in heavens would this be default behaviour? To hammer the stylesheet in this way. Is this a feature? If so why? Thank you

Comment: Because styles bleeding in and out of components always caused troubles. This is also a preparation step for when WebComponents becomr natively supported by all browsers, then Angular won't have to do anything itself and your existing Angular code will automativally use the native browser functionality.

Answer (score 19):

You should try this,

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
   ...
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
   ...
})
```

Comment: error: ReferenceError: ViewEncapsulation is not defined; Do I need to import it as well?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to tell u about that. Now check.

Comment: I have actually posted this answer from mobile so unble to give u any further reference. But please google for viewencapsulation in angular2 and i am sure u will learn lots of things about using  css in angular2.