# How do I append DOM to an Angular 2 component and still get encapsulated styles

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dom, d3.js, angular

I am upgrading an existing Angular 2 app that makes extensive use of JQuery Plugins, D3, and even some React Components (All of which use sizzle so I am pretty sure it applies to all). Since it really doesn't make sense to rewrite all of these at once I am trying to wrap some of them in an Angular 2 Component. To show you what I mean I have a simple component that uses Jquery to add an item to the DOM...

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:JQueryStatic;
@Component({
  selector: 'px-spinner',
  template: String(require('./spinner.template')),
  styles: [require('!raw!stylus-loader!./spinner.styles')]
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  constructor(public el:ElementRef){}
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    $(this.el.nativeElement).append("<div class='output'>Output 2</div>")
  }
}
```

The problem here is the styles are not applied to output 2. When I look at the DOM the reason becomes apparent...

```
<ng-spinner class="ng-scope" id="NG2_UPGRADE_0_pxSpinner_c0" _nghost-ylc-1="">
  <div _ngcontent-ylc-1="" class="start">
    <div _ngcontent-ylc-1="" class="output">output 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="output">Output 2</div>
</ng-spinner>
```

The DOM Element added by JQuery is missing the `_ngcontent-ylc-1=""`. Is there a way to have Ng2 add this when JQuery injects the DOM?

**Update**

The question is similar to this one ([Angular2 - adding [_ngcontent-mav-x] to styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224276/angular2-adding-ngcontent-mav-x-to-styles)) but I guess the question is how do I include the injected dom in the ViewEncapsulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a style like

```
:host .output {
  ... 
}
```

it should be applied.

If this doesn't work use

```
:host /deep/ .output {
  ... 
}
```

Comment: This would just make it global correct? I want to keep the ViewEncapsulation

Comment: Updated to reflect that I still want it isolated to DOM that is encapsulated in the component.

Comment: You can't include the inected DOM in ViewEncapsulation. The emulation is calculated either at build time (with AOT) or when the component was created. What might work though is to read the `_ngcontent-ylc-1` property from the components host element and apply it to your injected HTML as well. `/deep/` doesn't make styles global but the selector is rewritten so that the components children are addressed as well.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Gunter I will try that out and get back to you!

Comment: Also do I need the `:host` what is that doing?

Comment: Host is a selector that matches the current element. With `:host xxx` or `:host /deep/ xxx` all descendants elements that match `xxx` are addressed.

Comment: One question, does this work on older browsers that do not support shadow DOM? I haven't had time to try on IE10

Comment: Yes, `/deep/` and `>>>` are only processed by Angular2 and rewritten to styles that don't use these combinators. This is also why `/deep/` and `>>>` only work with `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` (default).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the _ngcontent-ylc-1 property in ngAfterViewInit from nativeElement. And then apply this property to your appended html.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this type of hacky fix, but it may be the only current option for some folks.

Comment: Yes, it's bad choice. Best solution is to rewrite it in a angular way.