# HTML code appearing as string

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Using Angular, I am calling a function inside a .html file, which returns a string containing a table element. I want this string to convert to html code.

I have tried [innerHtml]:

```
<p [innerHtml]="kalenderen(forsteUkedag('2016-08-01' | date:'E'), 8, 2016)"></p>
```

This works, printing the table, but the problem is that inside the table I have id/classes, unique for each cell, and I am not able to access them inside the .html file using this method. Styling the table from a CSS file is also not working. And I want to avoid inline CSS.

Any suggestions how to solve this so I can access the id/classes/objects?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the inserted HTML look like?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959273/render-css-for-innerhtml-using-angular2/39959334#39959334, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961645/how-do-i-append-dom-to-an-angular-2-component-and-still-get-encapsulated-styles/39961674#39961674

Comment: The inserted HTML is a string, with "<table>...'stuff'...</table"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need to insert html directly, what about this:

```
<p>
    <table id="yourId" class="yourClass">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let cell of cells" 
                [attr.id]="cell.id">{{cell.text}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</p>
```

Put all your html to the template, and component class only deals with data.

And in your component:

```
// Cell is like this:
// {id: string; text: string}
cells: Array<Cell[]>;
ngOnInit() {
    this.cells = this.getCells();
}
getCells() {
    let cells = .........;
    return cells;
}
```

Comment: I have tried, it did not work. I use a function to create the table cells, outputted as a string. So putting it inside {{ }} would only print the string, not running it as html code.

Comment: What i mean is, don't create html string(the table cells) in a function, just put all the html structure in the template, like: <table><tr><td>{{cellInfo}}</td><tr><table>, and only create the cellInfo property with functions

Comment: I can't, because I have functions to determine how many cells the table should have, not only putting a content in them.

Comment: What about *ngFor? It will render the cells you give to it dynamically, no matter how many.

Comment: You mean like <p *ngFor="let calendar of function()">{{calendar}}</p>? It doesn't show the table.

Comment: The problem is that I want all single cells to have a unique id. As far as I know, this will not work for that purpose. 
A solution might be that my function inside component exports it's return value to the html file? Is that possible?