# *ngContainerOutlet style not working with ng-component encapsulation

Tags: css, angular, components

I am using `*ngContainerOutlet` to dynamically load components, but it encapsulates the component's template in a `ng-component` tag, causing my CSS rules to fail.

For instance with :

```
<div class="my-class">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="MyComponent"></ng-container>
</div>
```

I end up with something like :

```
<div class="my-class">
    <ng-component>
        <div>my content...</div>
    </ng-component>
</div>
```

causing `my-class` to not be applied to the component's template.

I tried to create a CSS rule like `my-class > ng-component` but since it's dynamically created it doesn't work. Same with `:first-child`.

Is there a solution, either with CSS or Angular (for instance, prevent this encapsulation)?

Thanks,
Alexandre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

`::slotted` is now supported by all new browsers and can be used with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

**original**

You can use the `/deep/` combinator to overcome encapsulation:

```
:host /deep/ ng-component {
  ...
}
```

See also

- [Load external css style into Angular 2 Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542143/load-external-css-style-into-angular-2-component/34963135#34963135)
- [Angular 2: How to style host element of the component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853924/angular-2-how-to-style-host-element-of-the-component/36175093#36175093)
- [Styles in component for D3.js do not show in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214546/styles-in-component-for-d3-js-do-not-show-in-angular-2/36226061#36226061)
- [Angular2 - adding [_ngcontent-mav-x] to styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224276/angular2-adding-ngcontent-mav-x-to-styles/36225709#36225709)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!
This is link explains it : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html