# How do I change the CSS of pills ? (angular2)

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using Angular2 and ng-tabset from ng-bootstrap for my first website and managed to make it work so far.

However, I'm stuck now: I can't change the style of pills and they look like this : 
[image]

but I want them like this :

[image: desired]

it looks easy, I just need to display them horizontally and sit a reddish background !

Here is my code:

```
<ngb-tabset type="pills" orientation="horizontal">
<ngb-tab title="BN™ II">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <p>first visit</p>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-tab>
<ngb-tab title="BN ProSpec®">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <p>tab 2</p>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-tab>
<ngb-tab title="IMMAGE®">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <p>tab 3</p>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

I can only change the color of the bullet by adding this to my css file:

```
ngb-tabset {
    color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Kindly post a working fiddle of the same...

Comment: I don't have access to the html of the result I want to achieve, it's from a prototype on proto.io unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Thanks for the website link was able to recreate what you wanted. Add this CSS and it'll work.

**Old:**

Please find a sample of how to apply the CSS, I tried my best to replicate the image, you can find the styles in `style.css` inside the `Plunkr`

<kbd>**Plunkr Demo**</kbd>

**CSS:**

```
ul.nav-pills .nav-item {
    display: inline;
}

ul.nav-pills .nav-item > a {
    padding: 4px 35px;
    margin: 4px 5px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav-pills .nav-item > a.active {
    background-color: maroon !important;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: I tried using your css but it doesn't do anything.

I inspected my page and ng-tabset already has some css, however editing it doesn't seem to do anything either.

Moreover I don't know why `orientation="horizontal"` doesn't work.

I hosted my site : https://binding-site-app.firebaseapp.com
The tabs are under innovation > efficiency > unrivalled speed

Comment: @sheep Thanks for the link, updated my answer with the solution

Comment: At first it didn't work. I opened the style editor of Firefox and to my surprised there was a `[_ngcontent-c3]` after each class (for example : `ul.nav-pills[_ngcontent-c3]   .nav-item[_ngcontent-c3] {`) so I manually removed it in Firefox and it worked ! Thanks a lot ! This looks exactly like my image.

However, I don't how to prevent this `[_ngcontent-c3]` from being added, I need to fix this now. (the temporary fix is to paste it in the styles.css file at the root of my app, it's not edited that way)

Comment: @sheep I think there is some CSS file you are missing, that is why you are getting the issue, if I see the DEMOs on the internet they have some styling on them!

Comment: Actually, this is my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224276/angular2-adding-ngcontent-mav-x-to-styles I did this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36225709/8549201 fixed ! This is probably because the ngb-tabset is not up to date. Thank you again for your time.