# Angular2 styling issues caused by DOM attributes _ngcontent-* vs. _nghost-*

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have an issue with scss and the cli: angular adds an attribute `_nghost-fyw-1` to the apps tag (component) during runtime. at the same time it adds an attribute selector to my css called `_ngcontent-fyw-1` which of course won't work.

Do you have an idea how i could change this behavior/ avoid it?

PS: it also applies to regular css.

my components .scss file looks like this:

```
my-comp {
  h1 {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Well,

I found the answer myself. Using the default settings, you **must not** supply the wrapping `my-comp` element selector in the components css.

Instead use the `*` element selector to affect all elements nested in `my-comp`. Otherwise, angular will treat the `my-comp` selector as an additional element and thus add the `_ng-content-*` attribute, which of course is not present in the DOM.

Another option is to disable `ViewEncapsulation` for your component - be aware that it just affects the component `my-comp`

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  ...
});
```

https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-controlling-how-styles-are-shared-with-view-encapsulation explains the three different settings modes perfectly.

Comment: I don't understand the first part. Why should one use `*`? Isn't that what `:host` is for? Anyway, ViewEncapsulation.None saved my back when using an ancient syntax-highlighter. +1

Comment: In other words. Set `{ encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None } ` in the component declaration options.

Answer (score 18):

**update**

It's `::ng-deep` since a while.
See also the comments below.

**original**

You didn't provide too much details where you add your styles and what elements you target with the selectors.

The "official" way if you want styles to cross element boundaries is to use `>>>` like

```
:host >>> h1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

- `:host` targets the current element.
- `>>>` (or `/deep/`) makes Angular ignore `_nghost-xxx` attributes which is used for component style encapsulation emulation.

See also [Styles in component for D3.js do not show in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214546/styles-in-component-for-d3-js-do-not-show-in-angular-2)

Comment: (deprecated) /deep/, >>>, and ::ng-deep https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: You can ignore that deprecation. It will not go away before there is a replacement.

Comment: There will never be a replacement for a generic shadow-piercing selector operator, as it would defy the goal of style encapsulation. `::part` and `::theme` provide a viable, but not equivalent, alternative.

Comment: @MaxArt you are right of course, but that only slowly emerged during the years. `::part` and `::theme` weren't invented yet when I posted the answer. There was a `slotted` discussed i  the meantime. No idea where that went. I didn't follow development here since quite a while.

Comment: Fair enough, it was just a reminder for those who come across your answer and still hope for the future. Granted, `:ng-deep` *still* works in Angular 8. About the last part, are you referring to the [`::slotted` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted)? In that case, it will gain universal support as soon as Edge will become Chromium-based 

Answer (score 0):

::ng-deep works for me, adding into app.component.scss:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-card {
    background: #000 !important;
    color: #fff;
}
```

The documentation (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) says:

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is
>   being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop
>   support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until
>   then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with
>   the tools.

Use it, with precaution...